# Make instance methods of model A available in an associated model B?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Working on a gem which allows to add a time dimension (e.g. start_date, etc) to an arbitrary model.

**Module implementing ActsAsTimeable:**

```
module Timeable
  module ActsAsTimeable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_timeable(options ={})
        has_one :timeable_model, :as => :timeable, :class_name => "Timeable::Base", :dependent => :destroy
        ...
        delegate :start_date, :to => :timeable_model, :allow_nil => true
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Timeable::ActsAsTimeable
```

I skipped the details of Timeable::Base, but it has a setter **start_date=(val)** and a getter **start_date** (and of course many more).

**Problem:**

Due to the delegate method, I can do something like:

```
entity1 = Entity1.new (Model with acts_as_timeable added)
entity1.start_date => Sat, 28 Jan 2012
```

but I can't do

```
entity1.start_date = Date.today
```

I added the following code snippet before *module ClassMethods* to the module implementing acts_as_timeable:

```
def start_date=(val)
  build_timeable_model(:timeable => self) unless timeable_model
  timeable_model.start_date=(val) if timeable_model
end
```

But this does result in a **ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: start_date= is defined by ActiveRecord** when trying to initialize Entity1.new.

1.) What is the solution to this problem?

2.) Is there a more elegant way to make all public methods in Timeable::Base available in a  model which acts_as_timeable WITHOUT manually declaring each method in Timeable::ActsAsTimeable?